STL containers don't pretty-print when connected to gdbserver?
I have the following code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s{"qwe"};
    while (true){} // in order to attach
    cout << s << endl;
}

I run gdbserver with the command:
sudo gdbserver --attach localhost:2345 `pidof my_proj`

Then I run gdb and attach to gdbserver:
gdb
(gdb) target remote localhost:2345

As expected, it freezes on while (true){}, and when I'm trying to read the s variable I get the following output:
(gdb) print s
$1 = {
  _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<std::__new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x7ffea7445190 "qwe"}, 
  _M_string_length = 3, {_M_local_buf = "qwe", '\000' <repeats 12 times>, 
    _M_allocated_capacity = 6649713}}

It's not as pretty as I'd like it to be. But when I attach to my program directly with gdb and print the same variable, it looks quite pretty:
gdb -p `pidof my_proj`

(gdb) print s
$1 = "qwe"

What is the reason of such a behavior and how can I make the pretty printing work with gdbserver?

You probably have some settings in your .gdbinit file, it's not used when you run gdbserver with sudo.

Side note: nothing in this program needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.

@Barmar, I don't have a .gdbinit file in the home folder. I also tried to run gdbserver without sudo, but it didn't help

How are the pretty printers loaded? If it's by auto-loading of the libstdc++*-gdb.py file of your local libstdc++*.so, then it will not work for remote debugging.

If your gdbserver is (as in your example) running on localhost, then, before connecting to the remote, you could try using the set sysroot command.  This might help so long as GDB is able to read all the required files.  If gdbserver is running as sudo and GDB is not then GDB might not be able to read everything that gdbserver can, in which case the set sysroot command will not help.  But you can set sysroot, this might allow GDB's pretty-printer auto-loading work again as GDB will be loading libstdc++.so from the local file system, rather than from the remote target.

Thank you all, I just called set sysroot (just 2 words) before connecting to the remote and it worked. Though it seems strange that gdb loads printers from local files but doesn't do the same for remoted

Gdb server is usually not used to debug on localhost. In many cases the default pretty printer is not compatible with the stdlibc++ linked into the remote process, so gdb needs a hint about where to find target-specific debug information
